# CodeIgniter 2.0 with Modular Extensions (HMVC) not showing anything in Linux

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, modular

*edited to be more clearly

I'm deploying CI 2.0.3 with Modular Extensions (HMVC) in two environments, one is Windows -for development- and the other is Linux -for production-. Both environment has identically folders and files structure. Currently I am having a problem.

After integrating the Modular Extensions to CI by following the manual. The first thing I did was moving the default Welcome MVC that comes with CI to Modular Extensions HMVC. Both environment successfully moved and can be viewed on the browser.

But when I create other modules, it worked on Windows environment but not on Linux. On Windows when I call the module the browser shows the page as expected. But on Linux it shows just white blank page. Not even an 404 err page, which means it is not a broken link.

Can anyone tells me what is wrong in the CI?

Directory structure

```
/application
-/cache
-/config
-/controllers
-/core
--MY_Loader.php
--MY_Router.php
-/errors
-/helpers
-/hooks
-/language
--/english
-/libraries
-/logs
-/models
-/modules
--/csv_game_credit
---/controllers
----csv_game_credit.php
---/models
----csv_game_credit_db.php
---/views
----welcome_message.php
--/welcome
---/controllers
----welcome.php
---/views
----welcome_message.php
-/third_party
--/MX
--Base.php
--Ci.php
--Config.php
--Controller.php
--Lang.php
--Loader.php
--Modules.php
--Router.php
-/views
```

Welcome controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Csv_game_credit controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Csv_game_credit extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Csv_game_credit_db');

        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

}
```

Is this has something to do with the Linux's folder permission? I will try to change the folder permission to 777 and update you guys

Thanks before

Comment: Posting your controller and view code would be a good start.

Comment: you have to call the view from index() _very gently_

Comment: Turns out the Welcome module has the same file and folder permissions with the Csv_game_credit. So I don't think it is the cause.

Comment: The module works if I commented the $this->load->dbutil(); anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend MX_Controller not CI_Controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HMVC extension from [wiredesignz](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) you need to verify that you put the `MX` folder in the `application/third_party` folder and the `MY_Loader.php` and `MY_Router.php` in the `application/core` folder.

When this has been verified, create the folder `modules` in the `application` folder ('application/modules`).

**Now, what is a little tricky about this solution is that when you wan't to create a module, the default controller has to be named the same as the module - the default controller name specified in the config doesn't apply here.**

This means that if you create a module called `mymodule', you should create a folder/file structure like this:

```
application/modules/mymodule
- /controllers
- - mymodule.php
- /views
- - whatever.php
```

In the controller, located at `application/modules/mymodule/controllers/mymodule.php` you just create a controller as you would normally do:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mymodule extends CI_Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('whatever');
  }

}
```